# Enable "Current Page" in PrintDialog

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing, printdialog

Im using a `System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog` to let the user print one or more pages from my application. This is what I currently got:

```
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();

        printDialog.PageRangeSelection = PageRangeSelection.AllPages;
        printDialog.UserPageRangeEnabled = true;

        if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            // do print ...
        }
```

Im looking for the option to enable the **Current Page** radio button in the dialog. How to enable it?

Comment: May be it's some limitation of WPF? WindowsForms PrindDialog have property AllowCurrentPage.

Comment: Yes, Im looking for the direct counterpart of the System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog.AllowCurrentPage property. I dont think its a limitation of WPF, why would they keep the radiobutton? Seems like other parts of the dialog has changed.

Comment: I think WPF PrintDialog only uses standard printing dialog of Windows and does not give you API for change properties of this radiobutton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will decompile reference `PresentationFramework.dll` by Reflector you would be able to see that this class have nothing about CurrentPage. I think this radiobutton is disabled by default in Win32PrintDialog. In WinForms this radiobutton definitely is disabled by default:

```
    [DefaultValue(false), SRDescription(SR.PDallowCurrentPageDescr)] 
    public bool AllowCurrentPage {
        get { return allowCurrentPage;}
        set { allowCurrentPage = value;}
    }
```

I suppose that you can't enable this radiobutton, but I can be mistaken.

Comment: Seems like the best solution is to make my own dialog then. Thanks.